# Rendering specific values on React.js Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render some array/object values in a Modal with React. The problem is when I trigger the modal, values from all modals are rendered.

I searched and learned that it's because I need to store the value ID in state and then tell react to trigger that specific ID not all. But I don't know how to apply it.

Here's a basic example:

```
const items = [{id: 1, name: 'John', friends: ['Michael', 'Tom']},{id: 2, name: 
'Robert', friends: ['Jim', 'Max']}]

const [show, setShow] = useState(false); 
<>
{items.map((i) => {
<div key={i.id}>
<h1>{i.name}</h1>
<button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>View Friends</button>
</div>;
})}
{show ? <div>{items.map((i) => i.friends)}</div> : null} **I know this is wrong**
</>
```

So I was wondering how can I store the ID to let React know that I want that specific item to render and not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save `id` in state

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(null);
...
<button onClick={() => setShow(i.id)}>View Friends</button>
...
{show !== null && <div>{ items.find(i => i.id === show).friends }</div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the selection id in the component state.

```
const items = [{id: 1, name: 'John', friends: ['Michael', 'Tom']},{id: 2, name: 
'Robert', friends: ['Jim', 'Max']}]

const [show, setShow] = useState(false); 
const [id, setId] = useState(null);
<>
{items.map((i) => {
<div key={i.id}>
<h1>{i.name}</h1>
// set the user's selection into another local state
<button onClick={() => { setShow(true); setId(i.id)}}>View Friends</button>
</div>;
})}
// filter the current records for the selected id
{show && <div>{items.filter(obj => obj.id === id)?[0].friends}</div>}
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

First store the selected record in state like

```
const [selectedRecord,setSelectedRecord] = useState(null);
```

now when you click on button update selected record like this

```
<button onClick={() => { setShow(true); setSelectedRecord(i)}}>View Friends</button>
```

and use it to render inside modal like this

```
{show ? <div>name :{selectedRecord.name} Friends :{ selected.friends.join(',')}</div> : null}
```

Finally your code should be like this

```
const items = [{id: 1, name: 'John', friends: ['Michael', 'Tom']},{id: 2, name: 
'Robert', friends: ['Jim', 'Max']}]

 const [show, setShow] = useState(false); 
 const [selectedRecord,setSelectedRecord] = useState(null);
 <>
  {
    items.map((i) => {
     <div key={i.id}>
     <h1>{i.name}</h1>
     // set the user's selection into another local state
    <button onClick={() => { setShow(true); setSelectedRecord(i)}}>View Friends</button>
 </div>;
 })}
   {show ? <div>name :{selectedRecord.name} Friends :{   selected.friends.join(',')}</div> : null}
  </>
```